# How to parse the JSON and get the data row by row?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I would like to ask how do I get the data using the JSON. I am using the Web API and deploy using request and response.

Class1.cs

This is calling the web API by using the request and response.

```
public static string Test()

{

    string strReq = "{ \"header\": { \"Token\": \"ba42d11f - e0ae - 4d6c - 800a - 1564485b7ccb\"},\"body\": { \"SOHeaders\": [{ \"WarehouseCode\": \"W001\", \"CompanyCode\": \"C001\", \"SONo\": \"SO001\"}]}}";
    UploadToBCSSoftSCM a = new UploadToBCSSoftSCM();
    string strRes = a.GetSOSts(strReq);

    return strRes;
}
```

HomeController.cs

I can get the response from here but I don't know how to split or parse the data.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

    string r = Class1.Test();
    Debug.WriteLine(r);

    return View();
}
```

The result of response is

```
{
    "header": {
        "Token": "7c6cbeba-ff57-40d2-8759-84ccb59235fd",
        "DtTime": "2020-02-20 13:10:34.365",
        "ResultCode": "S",
        "ResultMsg": ""
    },
    "body": [
        {
            "WarehouseCode": "W001",
            "CompanyCode": "C001",
            "SONo": "SO001",
            "SOSts": "New"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what you want to parse? body within Json?

Answer (score 0):

O site [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) you can generate classes necessary to deserialize JSON.

```
public class Header
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string DtTime { get; set; }
    public string ResultCode { get; set; }
    public string ResultMsg { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
    public string WarehouseCode { get; set; }
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public string SONo { get; set; }
    public string SOSts { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Header header { get; set; }
    public List<Body> body { get; set; }
}
```

Then using [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you can deserialize your response into objects.

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

and then in loop you can reach all records

```
foreach(var d in data.body)
{
}
```

Comment: pretty sure that you can copy the json and in Visual Studio you can paste as Classes